# How to get metadata from a pdf file in ruby?

Tags: ruby, file, pdf, metadata, reader

I want to get the metadata from a pdf file in ruby.
Not just the date it was created but more like :

- Version
- Pages
- Security
- Created with - [ MOST IMPORTANT ONE ]
- CodingSoftware : MAC OS X 10.12.6

I have looked at pdfreader but I didnt find a way to extract this from a file

Comment: This is [built-in](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rmagick/Magick/Image#crop-instance_method) to the library you mentioned. Can we see a concrete example of a PDF file where the necessary metadata is not displayed by the gem?

Answer (score 0):

Most of this info is accessible with the `pdf-reader` gem:

```
require 'pdf/reader'

PDF::Reader.open("my-file.pdf") do |reader|
  puts reader.info.inspect
  puts reader.metadata.inspect
  puts reader.page_count
  puts reader.pdf_version
end
```

Comment: This didnt work for me. reader.metadata.inspect returns nil. I ended up using 'Henkei' that one works for me.